# Use of Stack with FittedBox in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stack with two icons. I would like to use the first icon within FittedBox so that the icon fills the whole available space.

When I wrap the first icon with FittedBox - the last doesn't work - the icons are built at their original size.

When I wrap the Stack with FittedBox - the both icons are filling the whole available space.

How could I get the desired result?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ));

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.abc),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                      height: 10,
                      child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the icon you want to expand in both a [`SizedBox.expand`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html) and then a [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ));

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox.expand(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Icon(Icons.abc),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```